# What is the location of the CG on the T-38?

Tags: stability, weight-and-balance, cg, t-38

Is the [Northrop T-38 Talon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_T-38_Talon)'s CG forward or aft of the center of lift (like the F-16)?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike conventional aircraft (and older fighters), the CG location of the F-16 makes the airplane unstable (making the aircraft more nimble), requiring fly-by-wire and a flight control computer to stabilize the aircraft.
Since the T-38 was designed prior to fly-by-wire technology, I would expect it to have been designed with a CG location that makes the aircraft inherently stable.

If the T-38 does have fly-by-wire, then my answer will get lots of down-votes, but I don't think that is the case looking at this:
https://mitindia.edu/images/pdf/avionics_ppt/stability%20and%20agumentation.pdf

Comment: I hate to play grammar police, but double negatives just drive me crazy. They introduce a level of confusion that is just unnecessary. Recommended text:  "I would expect it to have been designed with a CG location that makes the aircraft inherently stable."

Comment: The T-38 most certainly was NOT a fly-by-wire aircraft!  Its flight controls are entirely hydraulically powered, but those hydraulics are controlled by the pilot through conventional stick-and-rudders (with essentially a yaw damper to help out with the rudders a bit) -- no fancy computer fly-by-wire used, nor necessary.  Sub-sonic, the plane is nimble but not at all unstable; supersonic, it's very stable.  It's also much older than fly-by-wire technology; in fact it's a good example of how "inherent stability" is what the F-16 could leave behind with FBW and what you gain for doing so.

Comment: @Gerry  Done!  Thanks